# addBook (agregar un objeto a un arreglo)

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

Buen dia!
cito punto a realizar:

> // El método 'addBook' recibe un string 'book' y un string 'autor' y
> debe agregar un objeto:
> // { nombre: book, autor: autor} al arreglo de libros del emprendedor.
> // No debe retornar nada. addBook(book, autor) { // Tu código aca: }

**Lo cual mi codigo es el siguiente:**

> let info = {book, autor}
> this.libros.push(info);

**esto es en javascript**

Desearia saber cual es el error porque no lo estaria entendiendo. Desde ya muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: El ejercicio dice que la estructura (objeto) a agregar debe tener un campo (clave) `nombre` y un campo `autor`. El objeto que tu estás creando tiene una clave `book` y no `nombre`. Sin saber más de tu código, ya que no lo muestras (leer [mcve]) se me ocurre que construyas el objeto así: `let info = {nombre: book, autor};` y hagas la prueba. De todas formas, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"JavaScript está diseñado en un paradigma simple basado en objetos. Un objeto es una colección de propiedades, y una propiedad es una asociación entre un nombre (o clave) y un valor. El valor de una propiedad puede ser una función, en cuyo caso la propiedad es conocida como un método. Además de los objetos que están predefinidos en el navegador, puedes definir tus propios objetos."

Tu objeto debería ir de esa manera, el mismo ejemplo lo explica

```html
<script>
//Digamos que estas son tus variables
let book = "Dagon";
let nombreAutor = "HP Lovecraft"

//Aqui creas el objeto y lo almacenas
const info = {
    nombre: book, 
    autor: nombreAutor
}

//Para acceder al objeto 
console.log(info.nombre)

/*
* O podrias crear el objeto de esta forma
*/
const info2 = new Object();
info2.nombre = book;
info2.autor  = nombreAutor;

console.log(info2.autor)
</script>
```

Dejo a tu disposición la documentación sobre los objetos en JavaScript [Objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)